# How to change the structure of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, lodash

I have data retrieved from a database that I have transformed into:

```
"items": {
    "title - nameSection": [
        {
            "nameBoard": "xxx",
            "idTask": 1,
            "nameTask": "xxx",
            "contentTask": "xxx",
            "complete": 1,
            "idSection": 1,
            "nameSection": "xxx",
            "contentSection": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "nameBoard": "xxx",
            "idTask": 2,
            "nameTask": "xxx",
            "contentTask": "xxx",
            "complete": 1,
            "idSection": 1,
            "nameSection": "xxx",
            "contentSection": ""
        }
    ],
    "title 2 - nameSection": [
        {
            "nameBoard": "xxx",
            "idTask": 3,
            "nameTask": "xxx",
            "contentTask": "",
            "complete": 0,
            "idSection": 2,
            "nameSection": "xxx",
            "contentSection": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

which he obtained by using lodash:

```
   let grouped = groupBy(results, function (result) {
        return result.nameSection;
    })
```

My results are raw data from a database. 
I noticed that lodash sets my 'nameSection' as a key in JSON however I don't know how I could get the desired effect.
I'm trying with .map() (right?) To get this result:

```
"items": {
    "nameSection": "title - nameSection",
        "data": [
        {
            "nameBoard": "xxx",
            "idTask": 1,
            "nameTask": "xxx",
            "contentTask": "xxx",
            "complete": 1,
            "idSection": 1,
            "nameSection": "title - nameSection",
            "contentSection": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "nameBoard": "xxx",
            "idTask": 2,
            "nameTask": "xxx",
            "contentTask": "xxx",
            "complete": 1,
            "idSection": 1,
            "nameSection": "title - nameSection",
            "contentSection": ""
        }
    ],
        "nameSection": "title2 - nameSection", 
            "data": [
        {
            "nameBoard": "xxx",
            "idTask": 3,
            "nameTask": "xxx",
            "contentTask": "",
            "complete": 0,
            "idSection": 2,
            "nameSection": "title 2 - nameSection",
            "contentSection": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I will be grateful for any help and tips on how to solve the problem.

Comment: `items` should be array, right? Else you will not be able to use map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the object's entries to an object with a `nameSection` key and a `data` array, while overwriting the `nameSection` property in each object in the array:

```js
const items={"title - nameSection":[{nameBoard:"xxx",idTask:1,nameTask:"xxx",contentTask:"xxx",complete:1,idSection:1,nameSection:"xxx",contentSection:"xxx"},{nameBoard:"xxx",idTask:2,nameTask:"xxx",contentTask:"xxx",complete:1,idSection:1,nameSection:"xxx",contentSection:""}],"title 2 - nameSection":[{nameBoard:"xxx",idTask:3,nameTask:"xxx",contentTask:"",complete:0,idSection:2,nameSection:"xxx",contentSection:""}]};

const output = Object.entries(items)
  .map(([ nameSection, origData ]) => ({
    nameSection,
    data: origData.map(obj => ({ ...obj, nameSection }))
  }))
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me! What if I would like to extract idSection as in the case of nameSection (outside the array)?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with it, what are you looking for? Do you want the `idSection` as a key of the parent object? For a predictable output, each object in a sub-array would probably need to have the same `idSection` value, is that how things are? If so, I'd do `const { idSection } = origData[0]` before returning the object from the outer `.map` callback